# List of function arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A function of eight variables will be called as:

```py
f(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4)
```

Is it possible in the Python 3 to define such a function somehow like the following?

```py
def f(*vec_1, *vec_2):
    # unpack vec_1 of length 4
    # unpack vec_2 of length 4
    pass
```

That is, with two lists of arguments?

Comment: No. <12 more characters>

Comment: How, at runtime, would you be able to decide where to split the arguments? If you know it's four each, you should't be using that notation anyway. Just name all 8 or accept two lists.

Comment: You could at least call it like: `*(vec_1 + vec2)`

Comment: Well, yes, it's a bit strange, but I assume that during runtime it's always will be called with 8 arguments. So the best solution is to do something like this: `def f(*vecs)`, and inside a function split it manually: `vec_1, vec_2 = vecs[:4], vecs[4:]`?

Comment: Yes, that would be the right approach.

Comment: OK! Great, thanks!

Comment: it is possible to create a decorator for function that groups the arguments for you but if you have just a few of such functions it is not worth the confusion of adding such decorator though

Answer (score 0):

I suggest running this function as:

```py
def function(list_A, list_B):
    continue
```

If this approach is not possible in your case put some logic before the function call, which will verify which of those parameters should be assigned to proper list.

Or use dictionaries, there you can name every parameter and then act on them.

```py
dic = {a_1=1, a_2=2, b_1=3, b_2=4}
def function(dic):
    list_a = []
    list_b = []

    for key, value in dic:
        if 'a' in key:
             list_a.append(value)
        else:
             list_b.append(value)
```